# I broke my NPM registry and now can't create a react-app; where did I go wrong?

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, npx, hardhat

When I run commmand npx create-react-app This is the error I recieve, I do not know whereI went wrong? Any guidance on this situation?

```
PS C:\Users\ssand\wave_portal_3.0> npx create-react-app
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hardhart/create-react-app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ssand\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-05T23_31_09_147Z-debug.log        
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
PS C:\Users\ssand\wave_portal_3.0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reset your npm registry to the default with `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`